# How to solve "No glyph for U+000A in font Helvetica-Bold" in pdfbox (android port)

Tags: android, pdfbox

I want to write some text into a pdf. I have the data in "icrResultTxt". I am also writing the data to  [text.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06325337482879166990) file before trying to write to a pdf.  When I try to write to the pdf I get "**No glyph for U+000A in font Helvetica-Bold**". How to solve it? I dont have any fondness for "Helvetica-Bold". I am willing to change to any font.

```
  @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    Boolean ret = false;
                    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
                    try {
                        float scale = 0.8f; // alter this value to set the image size
                        formPreference = getSharedPreferences(SHARD_PREFERENCES,
                                MODE_PRIVATE);

                        PDPage page = new PDPage();

                        document.addPage(page);


                        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                                document, page, false, true);

                        PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
                        float fontSize = 25;
                        float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

                        PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
                        float margin = 72;
                        float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2 * margin;
                        float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
                        float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;
                        // icrResultTxt;//
                        writeToFile(icrResultTxt);  
                        String text = icrResultTxt; // "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox";
                        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                        int lastSpace = -1;
                        while (text.length() > 0) {
                            int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
                            if (spaceIndex < 0) {
                                lines.add(text);
                                text = "";
                            } else {
                                String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                                float size = fontSize
                                        * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
                                if (size > width) {
                                    if (lastSpace < 0) // So we have a word longer than
                                                        // the line... draw it anyways
                                        lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                                    subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                                    lines.add(subString);
                                    text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                                    lastSpace = -1;
                                } else {
                                    lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        contentStream.beginText();
                        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
                        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);
                        for (String line : lines) {
                            contentStream.drawString(line);
                            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
                        }
                        contentStream.endText();
                        contentStream.close();
                        File fz = new File(
                                Environment
                                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                        + File.separator + "hello.pdf");
                        if (!fz.exists()) {
                            fz.createNewFile();
                        } else {
                            fz.delete();
                            fz.createNewFile();
                        }
                        document.save(fz);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.v("mango", e.getMessage());
                }
private void writeToFile(String data) {
        try {

            File d = GetImageFile("test.txt");
            if (d.exists()) {
                d.delete();
                d.createNewFile();
            } else {
                d.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(d);
            try {
                stream.write(data.getBytes());
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just don't use codes that are not supported in a font. U+000A is not a glyph, it is a linefeed. Remove it.

Comment: im getting the string  from Abbyy Mobile Ocr SDK.. i cant remove anything :( , can you suggest me any other font that will not have problem with line feed .

Comment: Can you add custom fonts? https://www.google.com/get/noto/ covers most alphabets that you'd need.

Comment: They will all have trouble, because linefeeds are not glyphs. Linefeeds mean you should start a new line. What you should do is to fix the rest of the program, to split what you get and start a new line in the PDF. Or do this: line = line.replaceAll("\r\n","?") and you will get "?" instead of LF / CRs. This will of course look weird and won't make sense.

Comment: as prescribed i did: line=replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]","..."); but now getting "This font type only supports 8-bit code points". what to do bro ?

Comment: This is true; 16bit fonts are not supported in the 1.8 PDFBox versions. These are supported in the unreleased 2.0 version which has a different API, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#scm and https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html

Comment: i need a android port version !! is it  available ? :( .if there any bypass to the problem?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that one. I don't know. Best would be to look at the issues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code instead "\r\n"

```
   contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);  
    contentStream.drawString("hello"); 
    contentStream.endText();  
    contentStream.beginText();  
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 690);//the second parameter mast between 800.0 and 0.0
```

[image]